# Upvote/downvote function keeps running for ever even though it is set in an on click listener

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I've built a function to control the upvotes and downvotes on replies. Exactly like it works on SO.

It works perfectly fins - almost.

If I call it once (by clicking upvote or downvote), it is completely fine, but if I call it again (set it to 0 from -1 or 1), it starts running forever bouncing through -1, 0 and 1 (I am the only user so it doesn't get beyond 1 vote).

I can't understand what is causing this behavior. I'm thinking maybe it has something to do with the fact that it is inside a listener so the value change keeps igniting the function? If that's the case, how do I get the value I need without a listener? I'm not sure.. Help?

```
 private fun executeVote(vote: String) {


        val refVotes = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/votes/$answerId")
        refVotes.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                val refUserVote = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/votes/$answerId/$uid")

                if (p0.hasChild("$uid")) {
                    var voteValue = 0
                    refUserVote.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

                        }

                        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                            voteValue = p0.getValue().toString().toInt()

                            when (voteValue) {

                                1 -> {
                                    when (vote) {
                                        "up" -> refUserVote.setValue(1)
                                        "down" -> refUserVote.setValue(0)
                                        else -> refUserVote.setValue(0)
                                    }
                                }

                                0 -> {
                                    when (vote) {
                                        "up" -> refUserVote.setValue(1)
                                        "down" -> refUserVote.setValue(-1)
                                        else -> refUserVote.setValue(0)

                                    }
                                }

                                -1 -> {
                                    when (vote) {
                                        "up" -> refUserVote.setValue(0)
                                        "down" -> refUserVote.setValue(-1)
                                        else -> refUserVote.setValue(0)

                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }

                    })


                } else {
                    when (vote) {
                        "up" -> refUserVote.setValue(1)
                        "down" -> refUserVote.setValue(-1)
                        else -> refUserVote.setValue(0)
                    }
                }
            }


        })

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense because when you're calling setValue, the onDataChange will be called again, even though you are calling it from that same function.

When you're about to call setValue, remove the listener, call setValue, add the listener again (this is a typical Java way).

I would also avoid doing something in the else conditions, it's unneccessarily triggering events.

Comment: Thank you Pamela, two question: #1. How do I remove the listener and add it? Is their some function to do it? No sure what that means. #2. Should I just delete the else statements?

Comment: 1. Create the listener and save it as a val. Add the val and remove the val.

Comment: 2. I would remove the else statements, yes, or have empty else blocks :D

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in using addValueEventListener instead of addListenerForSingleValueEvent which I woudl assume as implied by name would listen once and let go.

Comment: You should accept Pamela Hill's answer and close this issue.